# How to detect content change event on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

I am trying to make an editor everything working fine till now, but now I need to make a handler which could detect any change made in a div or any content edited in the div

```
<?php $row="testing content" ?>
<!-- my editor section-->
<div id="editor">
    <div id="options">
        <span><a id="iimg">Insert Image from gallery</a></span>
        <span>Upload image to gallery</span>
        <span><a id="iheading">Heading</a></span>
    </div>
    <div id="product_descriptioncontent" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row; ?>
    </div><!-- viewable editor -->
    <input type="hidden" name="textareacontent" value="" id="textareacontent" >
    <!-- hidden field to submit values -->
</div>
<!-- end of editor section -->
<div id="imc"></div> <!-- image gallery loading section -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#iheading').click(function(){
    $('#product_descriptioncontent').append('<h1>Heading</h1>');
    });

    $('#iimg').click(function(){
        $('#imc').load('imagegallery.php',function(){
        $('#gallery img').on('click',function(){
            $('#product_descriptioncontent').append('<img  src="http://localhost/sites/site_pics/otherpic/1.png"><br>&nbsp;');
    });
    });
    });
    $('#product_descriptioncontent').change(function(){
    alert("pppp");// how to capture this event
    });
});
</script>
```

I have placed a bit of my code at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bipin000/UJvxM/1/
thanks for your precious time

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/: This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements

Comment: @Bipin use <input> and <textarea> elements and style at wish.

Comment: @Alon but textarea dosent seems to display images

Comment: @Bipin - I don't think there is a special event in jquery the detect content changing inside a DIV. I would use the [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to attach custom event to the div and [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) event on it upon change

Comment: I'm not understanding what type of change you are expecting and wanting to detect within the `div`?  Can you clarify that for me @Bipin?

Comment: Besides what Alon says about the .change() event, in the code you have above, you have a php echo of `$row` to populate that div.  If you are expecting that to change the div, as far as jquery is concerned, it's not because that `$row` is being inserted into the div _before_ jquery ever loads.

Comment: @JTSmith well i am trying to make and editor which may edit content loaded from database that is variable row in php and i have a hidden field too that contains the same content and when i make any change on the div the content of hidden filed should be updated with the all content (for this i need a event handler like change()) and i replace use html() to put all that content from hidden in the div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/hyPQC/

```
document.getElementById( 't' ).onkeypress = function( e ) {
    var evt = e || window.event
    alert( String.fromCharCode( evt.which ) )
}​
```

It's not waiting for a `change` event, it's kind of pointless.

Instead, it's listening to the `onkeypress` event. Everytime a user changes the content of this div (by adding a character to it), it triggers the event.

You can also see how to get the character clicked (using `String.fromCharCode( evt.which )`).

PS: a full jQuery solution for your specific case would be this:

```
$( '#product_descriptioncontent' ).on( 'keypress', function() {
    $( '#your-hidden-input' ).val( $( this ).text() )
    // Or
    $( '#your-hidden-div' ).text( $( this ).text() )
} )
```

Comment: `keypress` is not a good choice for this because it's not fired when content actually changes. For example on paste through mouse click, drag&drop etc.

Comment: [warning] the fiddler actually doesn't work because the js function is badly written. The 'document.getElementById' is only 'By'. Maybe someone doesn't see it and simply abandon the page. And also the div is not styled so you can't see it. It needs some adjustment, when I copy and paste the right code listed above, it works.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding a handler for [DOMCharacterDataModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent). Might be a cleaner solution.

Comment: According to Mozilla, "MutationObserver provides developers a way to react to changes in a DOM. It is designed as a replacement for Mutation Events defined in the DOM3 Events specification."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutation_events

Comment: linked page in answer is gone, 404

Comment: @fyngyrz mutation events have been deprecated, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a custom event to the div and trigger that event upon change

Demo in Stack Snippets and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKLmA/):

```js
$(function() {

  $('#wrapper').bind("contentchange", function() {
    console.log("Captured content change event"); 
  });

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').html("new value").trigger("contentchange");
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click here">
```