# get the size of label text inside the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I am trying to get the size of label text inside the div and chech of the size is 0  hide this div

Update the text is in dnn_ctr2802_View_lblHelp class dnnHelpText

javascript

```
  $('.dnnTooltip').dnnTooltip();
    //get the size of the hiden label
    var labelTextSize = $(".dnnHelpText").val().length;
    console.log("labelTextSize");

    if(labelTextSize == 0)
    {
        $('.dnnTooltip').hide()
    }
```

html

```
 <div class="pull-right eyeball">
    <img id="img_type" src="/ideaPark/DesktopModules/ExplorationTypeSaftyAlert/img/3.png" />
    <img id="img_safety_alert" class="eyeball-warning" src="/ideaPark/DesktopModules/ExplorationTypeSaftyAlert/img/exploration-warning.png" />
</div>

<div class="dnnTooltip">
<label id="dnn_ctr2802_View_label">
    <a id="dnn_ctr2802_View_cmdHelp" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;dnn$ctr2802$View$cmdHelp&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><span id="lblLabel"></span></a>

</label>
<div id="dnn_ctr2802_View_pnlHelp" class="dnnFormHelpContent dnnClear" style="display:none;">

    <span id="dnn_ctr2802_View_lblHelp" class="dnnHelpText"> bnmbnmbnmbnmtfgjnfvyg</span>
    <a href="#" class="pinHelp"></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this & BTW try to use jquery UI function .remove()

```
   var labelTextSize = $('.dnnHelpText').text().length;
    console.log("text:" + labelTextSize.length);
    if (labelTextSize == 1) {
        $('.dnnTooltip').remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var labelTextSize = $("#lblLabel").width();
```

And to test, try this:

```
console.log(labelTextSize);
```

UPDATE:

As anything worked I have search for other way to achieve this. I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15657686/1267304) and maybe it works for you.

Try this:

```
$(".dnnHelpText").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
    var labelTextSize = $(this).width();

    if(labelTextSize == 0)
    {
        $('.dnnTooltip').hide()
    }
});
```

That snipet add an event listener when the content of the `label` is been changed. So then, inside the event you may have access to it's properties to do your routine.

Comment: @ninjaDeveloper changing the selector to `$(".dnnHelpText")` didn't works?

Comment: it didn't work it labelTextSize =0 and it hide all di.vdnnTooltip

Comment: @ninjaDeveloper it's hard to tell without an live example. Try simulate it on jsfiddle with all stylesheet and desired behaviour.

Comment: that is the problem I'm using CMS bulletin tools tips