# jQuery How to call an event function without the event being triggered

Tags: jquery, function, call, onchange

I have a jQuery function as shown below. I want to call the function within my javascript regardless of the whether the triggering event occurs or not. In other words, there are circumstances where I simply want to call the function below. Is it possibe?

```
$(document).on('change', '.jq__pAC', function(event) {
  // some working code
}); // end .on('change')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is as follows:

```
function myFunction(event)
{
   // code stuff here
}
...    
$(document).on('change', '.jq_pAc', myFunction);
```

This way, you can call your function at your discretion, and it will also be called by the change event.

Comment: Thanks @BardMorgan -- sometimes you just spend too much time in the code and get lost in it. I need a fresh perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `change()`; without passing a function this method triggers the action, rather than handling it:

```
$(document).on('change', '.jq__pAC', function(event) {
 // some working code
}).change();
```

Alternatively you can use `trigger()`, which triggers the event passed to the method as a string:

```
$(document).on('change', '.jq__pAC', function(event) {
 // some working code
}).trigger('change');
```

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jQuery.com/change/).
- [`trigger()`](http://api.jQuery.com/trigger/).

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas -- sometimes you just spend too much time in the code and get lost in it. I need a fresh perspective.

Answer (score 3):

You can separate the function from the `on` method, like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.jq__pAC', handlerFunction);

function handlerFunction(event) {
  // some working code
}

// at some other point in your code you can call:
handlerFunction();
```

PS: Just for completion sake, I would recommend you extract the `event` variable inside the `on` method and pass only the appropriate info to `handlerFunction`.  Like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.jq__pAC', function(event) {
    var nodename = event.target.nodeName;
    handlerFunction(nodename);
});

function handlerFunction(nodename) {
  // some working code
}

// at some other point in your code you can call:
handlerFunction('div');
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve -- sometimes you just spend too much time in the code and get lost in it. I need a fresh perspective.

Answer (score 0):

So after a couple of minutes of testing and playing around with the change event I have noticed that this only works on input elements.

```
$(document).on('change', '.myCart-val', function(){
   if ($('.myCart-val').html() == "0") {
     $('.myCart-val').hide();
   } else {
     $('.myCart-val').show();
   }
});
```

What I have noticed is that for this function to actually go off I would need to apply it to some type of onclick event and the two would need to appreciate one another.

I have finally found a better solution that includes [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events). Mutation events allowed my function to run accordingly when triggered by another function.

My final solution.

```
if ($('.myCount').text() == "0"){$('.CartCount').hide();}

$('.myCart-val').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
   if ($(this).text() == "0") {
     $(this).hide();
   } else {
     $(this).show();
   }    
});
```

I found my answer [here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div) Hope it helps you