# JQuery catch an event on Paragraph change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make a script that, when the text of a certain paragraph change, start  a certain function, I tried the follow but i don't think the method change() works for a paragraph

```
$("#myParagraph").change(function(){......})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div

Comment: How is it changing?  I would assume via jQuery?  Can you catch that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would wrap that tag or "paragraph" in a container, and bind that container to a event possibly.  You could also look into using the length of the "text" property. During this triggered event, check that the state is different. I can write an example if you need one. One place to look at is the

```
//global variable. Store in hidden field if you would like.
var currentVal = $('element').text();


$('element').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  var newVal = $(element).text();
  if(currentVal != newVal)
  {
       //call function here.  
  }
});
```

This is basic and very simple, but to give you the idea.

Comment: Its not my website, i'm trying to make an extension,  to be more clear , the paragraph show a message every 5 minutes like that "aroud 10 min left"  "aroud 5 min left" , i would like to start a countdown of 5 minutes when it changes

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you please write me the part of the code independent from my function? I mean the part that checks if the value has changed