# I used jquery's toggleClass to add and remove but it's( <li> )list of <a> links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="/dashboard">
            <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
            <p>Dashboard</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="profile">
            <p>User Profile</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now what i want is if i click on one of this it will become active so what i did is-

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').bind('click', function() {
    $( this ).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

but the problem is it has no applied class after loading the page so i want it applid after loading the page i also tried toggleClass

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active'); 
});
```

any Suggestoins.. thank you..

Comment: So, you basically want to highlight the link of current page you are in. Am I correct?

Comment: @Mohanraj is correct, you need exactly that.

Comment: yes and my page is base page to another 5 pages so i want to  highlight the current page

Comment: yes I'm applying your answer only but anyhow it's not working, don't know why it should work btw great answer from you @alive ti die

Comment: yes it worked and I also found out that this Q is asked before me thanks for you great answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.Highlighting `<a>` based on current page:-***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = location.pathname;// Returns path
   $('.nav li a').each(function(){
     if(url.indexOf($(this).attr('href'))!== -1){
       $(this).addClass('active'); 
     }
   }
});
```

***2.OR Highlighting `<li>` based on current page:-***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = location.pathname;// Returns path
   $('.nav li a').each(function(){
     if(url.indexOf($(this).attr('href'))!== -1){
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: That's the certain solution OP is looking for, just his interpretation is different. and your quote of the day is true :-)

Comment: @bhansa  glad to hear . Appreciate for up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

I can realize that you are looking for something like this: [Adding active based on URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url)

First of all you need to define an `.active` css class, something like this:

```
.active{
    color:red;
}
```

then call your js when the page is ready:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').on('click', function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Instead of putting changes to `li` parent put it on li, because you want to toggle class for that itself.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qcsw2kcd/1/

Comment: [Is jquery .bind() deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654716/is-jquery-bind-deprecated)

Comment: this works for single click but when i click it it will redirect to another page so i wnt class applied at that page also. and obvio i have defined it

Comment: I have given `#` as href in link for now, OP will have to handle it through js.

Comment: how about adding the class directly in that page?

Comment: my <li> contains <a> so effects fades away i want it applied on redirected page also