# Detect changes to the html of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basicially I have 4 divs with the same class names. If the text from "option2" change to e.g "newoption" how can I add a class to the matching div?

```
<div class="htmlchange">option1</div>
<div class="htmlchange">option2</div>
<div class="htmlchange">option3</div>
```

**Example:**

```
<div class="htmlchange">option1</div>
<div class="htmlchange addclass">newoption</div>
<div class="htmlchange">option3</div>
```

Comment: How the text will be change (from js,by the user)?

Comment: The text change from js

Comment: Add this part that change the text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Event : Detect changes to the html/text of a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

if you are changing the html of those `htmlchange div` with JS you can simply add your class to that element right there. Or based on this article you can spy on Document DOM tree https://davidwalsh.name/dom-events-javascript 
 Otherwise `change` `event` does not trigger for `div` .This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements .

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/tg5op333/31/  
HTML

```
<div class="htmlchange">option1</div>
<div class="htmlchange" id="2">option2</div>
<div class="htmlchange">option3</div>
<input type="button" id="change" value="change">
```

JS:

```
$('.htmlchange').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
 $(this).addClass('changed');
});

$("#change").click(function(){
    $("#2").html('changed');
  //you can either add from here or use  DOMSubtreeModified handler above   
  $("#2").addClass('changed');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind to a custom event

```
 $(".htmlchange").click(function() {
      $(this).trigger('contentchanged');
    });


    $(document).on('contentchanged', '.htmlchange', function() {
      // do something after the div content has changed
      $(this).addClass('test');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="htmlchange">option1</div>
<div class="htmlchange">option2</div>
<div class="htmlchange">option3</div>
```

Javascript which includes JQuery

```
$(".htmlchange").bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function() {
$(this).addClass('someotherclass');
});

$("div.htmlchange").each(function (docindex) {
    if (docindex==1)
    {
         $(this).text("someotherclass");
     }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mehtaniravm/cwnu4xaj/14/#&togetherjs=83ejg4EPB0)

And the last part I added in javascript is only for the demo purpose to change the content in option 2

```
$("div.htmlchange").each(function (docindex) {
if (docindex==1)
{
$(this).text("someotherclass");
}
});
```

Hope this helps!!! Happy Coding!!!!