# How can i trigger content changes inside a pre tag using jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to edit content inside the "pre" tag. On a button click i want to know whether the content is changed or not. How can i possible this using "jquery"?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: `pre` tag is not input tag and does not have `change` event

Comment: is it possible only with input tag? by adding an attribute conetnteditable=true we can edit content inside all elements. then there should be a way in jquery to trigger that change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Event : Detect changes to the html/text of a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div)

Comment: @Nighinatt did my answer help you?

Comment: yes .. thank u for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `DOMSubtreeModified`

```js
$('.change-text-button').on('click', function(){
    $('.my-pre').text('Some other text');
});



$('.my-pre').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  console.log('changed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="change-text-button">Change text</button>
<pre class="my-pre">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</pre>
```