# Keep Div scrolled to bottom

Tags: php, jquery, html, scroll

I know numerous questions have been asked about this, but I've not seen one that is the same as my requirement.

I have a `div` and data is added to it by calling an external page and then writing the results live to the div. That works fine using:

```
<div id='test'>

$x = popen("php test.php", 'r');

while($y = fgets($x, 512)) {
    echo "$y<br>";
    ob_flush();flush();
}
pclose($x);

</div>
```

test.php is echo'ing its results and the div is updated.

I need to keep `test` div scrolled to the bottom.
I've been doing it by adding a new line after the echo `$y` like so:

```
echo "<script>var objDiv = document.getElementById(\"test\");objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;</script>";
```

But I feel there is a better way to do that then keep echoing that script.

Can anyone advise how to keep the div scrolled to the bottom ?

Is there no way to bind an event that detects content change on the div and then scrolls to the bottom, without having to echo the same code over and over ?

Thanks

The ticket referenced as a duplicate is discussing scrolling to the bottom of the div, NOT how to scroll to the bottom of the div as it it being updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [bind-Event](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$('.box').bind("DOMSubtreeModified propertychange", function(e) {
    $(this).animate({ scrollTop: $(this).prop("scrollHeight") }, 100);
});
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w19c4yvs/2/)

if you retrieve the data over ajax `$(document).on()`

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified propertychange", ".box", function(e) {
        $(this).animate({ scrollTop: $(this).prop("scrollHeight") }, 100);
});
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w19c4yvs/3/)

Source:
[Jquery Event : Detect changes to the html/text of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div)

> `DOMSubtreeModified` is not working on IE.

Edit: Added `propertychange for IE-support.

Comment: thanks for this is there a way to do this across browsers ?

Comment: edited answer. this should work in ie (cant test it right now)

Comment: Thanks - Just tried this in Chrome and it didn't work. Data is added to the div but it doesn't scroll to the bottom.

Comment: are you retrieving your data over an ajax-request? if so use `$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified propertychange", ".box", function(){});`