# jQuery onChange() does not work…

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I tried making a simple on change fiddle. I can't get it to work. No matter what I do. WHY?

HTML CODE

```
<div id="status" style="display:none">0</div>
<button class="start">GO</button>
```

Javascript CODE

```
var cntTo = 2;
var cnt = 0;

$('#status').change( function() {
  console.log('status changed');
  if ($(this).text() == '1'){
    if(cnt <= cntTo){
      getNext(cnt);
    }
  }
});



$('.start').click(function(){
  console.log('start clicked');
  console.log('text of status now: ' + $('#status').text());
  if($('#status').text() != '1'){
    console.log('setting text');
    $('#status').text('1');
    console.log('text of status now: ' +$('#status').text());
  }
});

function getNext(cnt){
  $('#status').text('0');
  console.log('getting details');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hakz47vg/

Comment: on change event will not work for a `<div>`

Comment: but I have also tried. 
$(document).on('change','#divid', function () {
 // and this doesn't work either.
})

Comment: Use `<input name="status" type="hidden" value="0" />` and change `.text()` to `.val()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$('#status').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
```

```js
 
  var cntTo = 2;
 var cnt = 0;
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.start').click(function() {
     if ($('#status').text() != '1') {
       $('#status').text('1');
     }
   });
   $('#status').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
     console.log('fired');
     if ($(this).text() == '1') {
       if (cnt <= cntTo) {
         getNext(cnt);
       }
     }
   });
 });


 function getNext(cnt) {
   $('#status').text('0');
   console.log('getting details');
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status" style="">0</div>
<button class="start">GO</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have marked yours instead as it as before the other person's. I didn't see it first. But I have changed my choice.

Comment: @GrafixMastaMD I'm glad i was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The .change() function is limited to input, textarea, and select.
Source: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

You can embed `onchange` function code directly with GO button click event like this:

```
$('.start').click(function(){
    if($('#status').text() != '1'){
        $('#status').text('1');
    }
else
{
  if(cnt <= cntTo){
    getNext(cnt);
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Himanshu. I could do this but I can't do this. Because I will be using ajax to make calls. Then the ajax success function updates the hidden field to be 1 again. If you notice the getNext function updates it to be 0. so that way when ajax returns it's value it will fire off the next record and I can visually see each record being processed.

Comment: ok @GrafixMastaMD, you can use `DOMSubtreeModified` as others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DOMSubtreeModified` event

> `DOMSubtreeModified`  This is a general event for notification of all changes to the document. It can be used instead of the more specific mutation and mutation name events. [Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#domsubtreemodified)

```
$('#status').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  alert('changed');
});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sszL1vx9/2/)

another simple solution

when text in `#text` changes in script fires a trigger and you can bind it to change event

```js
 var cntTo = 2;
 var cnt = 0;
   $('#status').bind('change', function () {
      console.log('fired');
   if ($(this).text() == '1'){
    if(cnt <= cntTo){
     getNext(cnt);
    }
   }
    });
 
 $('.start').click(function(){
  if($('#status').text() != '1'){
   $('#status').text('1');
             $('#status').trigger('change');
  }
 });
 
 function getNext(cnt){
  $('#status').text('0');
  console.log('getting details');
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status" style="display:none">0</div>
<button class="start">GO</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is closest I have got. It's a little tricky to work with. But I think with some if statements I can definitely accomplish my goal. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: You welcome :) i have added another simple solution similar to what you have done check that once updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

`$("start").click` function put inside in ready Function

Answer (score 0):

You are using `change` event which does not watch or respond to div content.Use `DOMSubtreeModified` event and trigger action on that event.

```js
var cntTo = 2;
var cnt = 0;

$('#status').on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  if ($(this).text() == '1') {
    if (cnt <= cntTo) {
      getNext(cnt);
    }
  }
});
$('.start').click(function() {
  if ($('#status').text() != '1') {
    console.log('setting text');
    $('#status').text('1');
    console.log('text of status now: ' + $('#status').text());
  }
});

function getNext(cnt) {
  $('#status').text('0');
  console.log('getting details');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status" style="display:none">0</div>
<button class="start">GO</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some action when the content modified inside the `div` element you have to use the event called `DOMSubtreeModified` like below.

```
 $("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#status", function() {
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hakz47vg/2/)

**Reference:**

For more information read out the thread already discussed about this in stack overflow.

[jQuery Event : Detect changes to the html/text of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div)