# How to detect if a div is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a number of `divs` each has the property `contenteditable="true"`, I am able to detect when the user clicks or hovers over an element using JQuery, but how can I tell if the `div` is selected i.e. the text cursor appears within div and is ready to accept text input.

Ideally I am after a JQuery solution.

This isn't a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div) as question marked does not take into consideration that a div is selected but not being edited!

Comment: What research or attempt(s) have you done so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Event : Detect changes to the html/text of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div)

Comment: @NewToJS  Browsed throug CSS selecters and JQuery methods. Googled around a bit and attempted to see whether I can detect whether the text cursor is being displayed within the div or not.

Comment: @DanieleFois but I also want to detect whether the div is simply selected, the user may not have entered something yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any other attribute you can hook into the focus() event. See the [jquery focus() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) for more information

```
<div id="editBox" contenteditable="true" style="border 1px solid">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#editBox').focus(function() { alert('focused');  });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was after.