# How to create a script to detect content changes on refresh?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, page-refresh

Just starting out as a programmer, so just trying to learn the ropes and all.

I'm trying to create a script or program of some sort that can run almost like an extension in Chrome, but basically does two things.

1. Refreshes the page every x seconds.
2. On the page refresh, if it notices that a certain part of the text on that page has changed since the last refresh, stop refreshing and notify the user.

I know there are Chrome extensions out there that already do the page refresh, but I can't seem to find anything that combines the refresh and the page content change detector.

Any help or hints on where to even start with how to program this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Once you gain some experience with DOM and extensions this task will be a no-brainer. Currently it's not clear what's stopping you from implementing what you want except from the lack of experience. See [extensions overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) and [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: You could start by making a userscript using Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey, it'll be a little easier than making a Chrome extension. In there you can use the `DOMSubtreeModified` event as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div)

Comment: @maxpleaner that's not applicable here, the page is reloaded. Yes it's possible, an extension would be the best approach. it would start by knowing which elements might change and storing them or their content in local storage. On each page load, compare the elements with what's in the local storage, do whatever alerting you need and then store the latest in the local storage.