# Keep checking If Div contains specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement

Hello So I want to keep checking a function and if a div contains a specific text here is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working any ideas?

JS

```
var interval = 500;
var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    var text = $('.text-split-original').text();
    var checkText = '4) PLACEHOLDER '

    if(text == checkText){
        alert("It has this text");
        //do something
    };
}, interval);
```

HTML

```
<div class="sar__label">
    <div class="text-split-original">
        4) PLACEHOLDER 
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what might be changing the content of that div?

Comment: I guess `checkText` should be something else that the default content that you have in your div right?

Comment: I believe `.text()` works on all elements of the collection. So may just take the first one `$('.text-split-original').eq(0).text()`

Comment: Trimming your text will get you closer: `var text = $.trim($('.text-split-original').text());`... but I wonder why you're doing this... there's almost always a better solution than polling.

Comment: Should also trim  the checkText var... it has a space at the end.

Comment: `console.log(escape(text), escape(checkText))`

Comment: Apparently checkText is not defined my code is blow all other scripts and jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to trim the spaces off and it works fine.

```js
var interval = 500;
var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    var text = $.trim($('.text-split-original').text());
    var checkText = $.trim('4) PLACEHOLDER ')

    if(text == checkText){
        alert("It has this text");
        //do something
    };
}, interval);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sar__label">
    <div class="text-split-original">
        4) PLACEHOLDER 
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to trim ```checkText```, could directly do ```var checkText = '4) PLACEHOLDER'```

Comment: Trim everything! I wanted to change as little of their code as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `.trim()` will remove the whitespace that is causing the comparison to fail:

`var text = $('.text-split-original').text().trim();`

Additionally, the `checkText` string `'4) PLACEHOLDER '` contains an extra space at the end, which will also break the comparison.

Beyond that, running an interval is not the most efficient way to do things. <s>Perhaps you may want to [look at when the contents of the div change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div) instead.</s> **edit**: This is deprecated as pointed out by @Barmar, see [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead.

See your fixed code here (I've commented out the interval to prevent spamming yourself): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMRbMx

Comment: The `DOMSubtreeModified` event used to detect changes is deprecated, so it's not a good idea to recommend it.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for pointing that out, I wasn't aware. The answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Without JQuery:

```
<html>
<script>
var interval = 500;
var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    var text = document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML;
    var checkText = 't'
    console.log(text);
    console.log(checkText);

    if(text == checkText){
        alert("It has this text");
        //do something
    };
}, interval);
</script>

<div class="sar__label">
    <div id="myId" class="text-split-original">t</div>
</div>

</html>
```

I've intentionally erased all the spaces in the div. You need to trim() the spaces, or manipulate the text to match you case.

Answer (score 0):

A great plugin to do just this is at https://j11y.io/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/ -- and yeah, it does so by setInterval/clearInterval. But the idea of a simple watch() plugin makes me happy.

Granted, its older (ca. 2009), but it still works.

```js
/**********
 * jQuery plugin to allow monitoring of any
 *  DOM el's properties. It does so by
 *  a setInterval/clearInterval hook. Taken from
 * https://j11y.io/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/
 **********/

jQuery.fn.watch = function(id, fn) {

  return this.each(function() {

    var self = this;

    var oldVal = self[id];
    $(self).data(
      'watch_timer',
      setInterval(function() {
        if (self[id] !== oldVal) {
          fn.call(self, id, oldVal, self[id]);
          oldVal = self[id];
        }
      }, 100)
    );

  });

  return self;
};

jQuery.fn.unwatch = function(id) {

  return this.each(function() {
    clearInterval($(this).data('watch_timer'));
  });
};

/***** 
 * This is the part that does stuff.
 *   The updater updates that content div
 *   and the contentEl.watch leverages the
 *   above extensible plugin. It's watching
 *   the vanilla 'innerText' attribute of
 *   that DOM el.
 *****/

var contentEl = $(".content");

$(".updater").on("keyup", function() {
  contentEl.text($(this).val())
})

contentEl.watch("innerText", function(propName, oldVal, newVal){
    console.log('Text has been changed from '+oldVal+' to ' + newVal);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">

</div>
<input type="text" class="updater" />
```