# How to get live data from HTML element by JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Element

```
<span class="bar">xxx</span>
```

contain value and it's updated by Ajax.

I have successfully get this **xxx** data to variable via JQuery with this script

```
var foo = $('.bar').html();
$("#other").append("<strong>" + foo  + "</strong>");
// alert(foo) <- for testing
```

to append it to #other place in page, and it's works fine but...
How to get live data (updated by Ajax) from this .bar element?

Comment: You can attach event to the bar element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div

Comment: So when the `<span class="bar">` is updated you want the text to be updated into #other also?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen exactly

Comment: @RauliRajande i will check it!

Comment: Why downvote? :(

Comment: You mentioned that value in `.bar` is updated by AJAX, why not update '#other' in the same AJAX success callback?

Comment: @PipBoy2000 Another option would be to put this update bit to the ajax success method.

Comment: @Junaid because second mutiple .bar class cause ajax problems. i don't want to override any ajaxcalls. just grab .bar data to separate variable and manage it by my own little script

Comment: you could use a callback or attach an event to #other element, for instance  attach onchange to that element, once that element change you update the  $(.bar) element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .on() as .bind() is deprecated!

```js
// to simulate ajax changing contents
$('.ajax').on('keyup', function(){
  $('.first_div').html($(this).val())
})

// your answer
updater();

$('.first_div').on('DOMSubtreeModified', updater)

function updater(){

  var data = $('.first_div').html();
  
  // your logic here
  data = '[' + data + ']'

  // display result
  $('.second_div').html(data)
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
Enter new content:
<input class="ajax" value="initial">

This is what ajax updates:
<div class="first_div">initial</div>

This is updated by DOMSubtreeModified event:
<div class="second_div"></div>

</pre>
```

Comment: Works well only when .first_div is updated - as expected. When .first_div is unchanged throws nothing. Any idea how to manage this case?

Comment: @PipBoy2000 I moved updating to updater() function, which could be called on page load, seems to work with jQuery 1.11.0 too

Comment: Top notch! Love it! :)

Comment: I hope this solution will help a lot of people too :) Now i will need to get this grabed data as variable to make some logic :D

Comment: Thanks :) I added logic part as well

Comment: holy lord bro! :) Made my day!! Best regards from Poland!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
$('.bar').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  $("#other strong").text($(this).text());
});
```

It will update `#other strong` when `.bar` is modified. aka when its updated.

```js
var foo = $('.bar').text();
$("#other").append("<strong>" + foo + "</strong>");


$("button").click(function() {
  $('.bar').text("new data");
})

$('.bar').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  $("#other strong").text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="bar">xxx</span>

<div id="other"></div>


<button>add new content to bar</button>
```