# Detect div > ul has been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some test code.

```
 <div class="someclass" id="someid">
    <div class="form-someclass1 class2 ">
    <div class="button action right addbutton" id="btnId"><i class="add"></i> Add</div>
   </div>
    <ul class="ui-sortable">
           <!-- dynamically li gets added. -->
    </ul>
  </div>
```

As soon as we click on "btnId" li gets added in ul and div has been changed. Similarly, if we remove li ul gets changed and div has been changed. **Is there any way to get information that div > ul has been changed and on which event should we trigger the code in order to know change?** 
I tried for DOMSubTreeNodeChanged mutator events but as per google, it has compatibility issues and not to use.

Comment: Try to look at this [mutator event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div)?

Comment: I think this might work for you as mentioned by @gitguddoge. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```js
$("#btnId").on('click', function(e){
    //alert(1112);
    var target = $(this).closest(".someclass").find(".ui-sortable");
    target.append('<li><a href="/user/messages"><span class="tab">Message Center</span></a></li>');
});

$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    //check if li inserted to ul
    if(e.target.localName == "li"){
        //do somethings!
        console.log("Inserted a li for ul!");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="someclass" id="someid">
        <div class="form-someclass1 class2 ">
            <div class="button action right addbutton" id="btnId"><i class="add"></i> Add</div>
       </div>
        <ul class="ui-sortable">
               <!-- dynamically li gets added. -->
        </ul>
    </div>
```