# re-rendered HTML is not being affected by jQuery functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6

A couple of minutes ago I faced a situation where I needed to do some functions whenever some events were triggered like:

`<button>Default button</button>` and then a script like:

```
$('button').click(() => $('body').append(`<button>Re-rendered button</button>`));
```

So I was searching for a `$(document).change()` function and I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div) that worked great for my situation:

```js
$(document).bind('DOMContentLoaded DOMSubtreeModified', () => {
  $('button').on('click', () => {
    $('body').append(`<p><button>Another button</button></p>`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>First Button</button>
```

In fact, this code here adds three buttons, but on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tinchoeluru/pen/PyGYEX) works as intended.

So, the question is, how should I apply (as a best practice) the same logic in order to let the new buttons be affected by jQuery functions?

Comment: Don't use `DOMSubtreeModified` - it's been deprecated for some time. If you wanted to do this in this manner, use a MutationObserver. ***However*** as you're using jQuery just use a delegated event handler.

Comment: It will also compound more events onto the previously created buttons. Meaning if you hit one of the previous buttons you will get increasingly more buttons each time you click one.