# Trigger function if value is dynamically changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` that is dynamically changed, and I need to trigger a javascript function when a property of the `div` is changed.

`Inputbox` has a property named `onChange`.  Is there something similar for `divs`?  I need the function to trigger when values like `background-color`, `height`, `top`, etc. are changed.

`<div id="hello" onChange="Changed()">Espinete</div>`

`function Changed(){alert('The div was changed');}`

Comment: Note that the best answer in the duplicate is regarding the use of a Mutation Observer to achieve what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42805882/519413. The answers suggesting DOMSubtreeModified are outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The solution below is deprecated, sorry.

Try using the `DOMNodeInserted` and `DOMNodeRemoved` events.

```
$('#hello').on('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function() {
    alert('The div was changed');
});
```

Comment: Note that the events you've used in your edit are still deprecated. In fact, all mutation events are: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**MutationObserver**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Here is a demo

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');

setTimeout(() => div.style.backgroundColor= "red",2000);

var data = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

let x = new MutationObserver((list) => {
  console.log(list[0].target.style.backgroundColor)
})
x.observe(div,data)
```

```html
<div>Something</div>
```