# How do I apply animations of <div> on text change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div>`, to display the text. And given animation for the `<div>`.
I want to animate the `<div>` when change the text. How do I change the css

**HTML**

```
  <div id="location-name-container">
         <div id="location-name"></div>
    </div>
    
    document.getElementById('location-name').innerHTML = "Hello"
```

**CSS**

```
#location-name {
    align-self: center;
    width: 540px;
    max-height: 100px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000000;
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    animation: fade-in 200ms;   
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
  }
  
  @keyframes fade-out {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
  }
```

[Click here to access the sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/ny67j9sb/1/)

Comment: How the text is going to change? is there any event?

Comment: You will need JavaScript to look for the change in the content. Add your animation to a class property, then add the class via JavaScript when the change occurs.

Comment: put the animation in a seperate css class and attach the class to the div when text changes , as Martin said :)

Comment: I think you should have a look on this thread to get 
the event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div

Comment: @Vaibhav: - there is event to chane the text. It is working fine. But, I do need to run the animation also.

Comment: @Rmaxx: It is in separate css class- I just copied the relavent code here.

Comment: seperate as in , not initial...  like '.isAnimating'

Comment: @Rmaxx: here is the sample code, https://gist.github.com/vineeshtp/d54439bf3fc0300deedb36edecdbdacf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a simple example.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="data-container" id="first-container">
   <div id="location-name-container">
        <div id="location-name" class="run-animation">Hello</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <script>
 setInterval(myFunction, 3000)
 var a = 1
 
 
 function myFunction(){
 locationname = document.getElementById('location-name');
 locationname.classList.remove("run-animation");
 void locationname.offsetWidth;
 locationname.classList.add("run-animation");
 
 locationname.innerHTML = "Hello"+a
 
 a++

 }
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#location-name {

    background:#003344;
    align-self: center;
    width: 540px;
    max-height: 100px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000000;
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    
}

.run-animation {
  /* position: relative; */
  animation: fade-in 2s linear;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
   0%{
   color:black;
  }
  30%{
  color:blue;
  }
  80%{
  color:green
  }
 
  
   from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
  }
  
  @keyframes fade-out {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
  }
```

[Click here to see the original post](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind a custom event for such a task with your HTML components in js :

```
 $(document).on('contentchanged', '#location-name', function() {
      alert('woo');
    });

$('#location-name').trigger('contentchanged');
```

In this example, once your content will update you will see an alert you can replace alert code with your custom code.

```
 <div id="location-name-container">
      <div id="location-name">India</div>
</div>
```

Triggering the event:- when below line execute custom event will be a trigger

```
document.getElementById('location-name').innerHTML = "Hello"
```

[updated fiddle]
https://jsfiddle.net/niteshsharma/wgqc69s8/1/

Comment: How do I restart my animation.

Comment: give me your running js fiddle as I tried with your CSS it was not not showing anything in HTML

Comment: Here the sample code- it changing the text , https://gist.github.com/vineeshtp/d54439bf3fc0300deedb36edecdbdacf

Comment: please have a look [https://jsfiddle.net/d6j3sk0u/1/] (https://jsfiddle.net/d6j3sk0u/1/) it will work whenever your div text change your animation will reset and run again

Comment: I used this , https://jsfiddle.net/d6j3sk0u/1/ and chnaged the text using 'setInterval(myFunction, 3000)' but, is not woking. Text is changing but Animation not happening. Here is the code, https://jsfiddle.net/3d2q9vg7/

Comment: check I updated the fiddle it's working as expected as there was no `myFunction` specified  now its working [https://jsfiddle.net/uxtynv0p/](https://jsfiddle.net/uxtynv0p/)

Comment: pleaase check this, https://jsfiddle.net/3d2q9vg7/. Thanks.

Comment: please check the updated fiddle in the answer if this what you are expecting then please accept the answer it will motivate to help others.

Comment: It is working fine. but, Is there any other way to do this? ie, set the animation for the parent <div> then animate to all child elements like that,  I am new to this so, don't have much idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JavaScript to restart the animation right after you change the content. Check out this tutorial:
https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addText() {
  const elem = document.getElementById('location-name')

  setTimeout(() => {
    elem.innerText = "Hello"
    elem.classList.add('animate-text')
  }, 10);
  
  // REMOVE CLASS & TEXT TO VISUALIZE EFFECT
  elem.innerText = ""
  elem.classList.remove('animate-text')

}
```

```css
#location-name {
  align-self: center;
  width: 540px;
  max-height: 100px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000000;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.animate-text {
  animation: fade-in 1s;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div id="location-name-container">
  <div id="location-name"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="addText()">Add text</button>
```