# How to detect change on the div text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to detect when div text is changed. I have multiple buttons which every one can change the text in the div. Unfortunately,the following code doesn't work. I also read that DOMSubtreeModified and Mutation area  are deprecated and solutions in stackoverflow don't work for me.

```
(function($) { 

$('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', '.heading-price', function(){
  console.log('changed');
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: .heading-price is a div with price.
I have multiple buttons on site, every one is changing a price in above div. I need to detect when price is changing so i cant use click event.

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan I think you're misunderstanding what's being asked.

Comment: reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div

Answer (score 0):

You can call it simply like:

```
$('body').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){alert('changed');});

$('body').append('<h1>hello</h1>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("divId").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", (event)=>{
    console.log(event)
});
```