# get div Tag value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I really dont know how get the div tag in between value Which in this case is

> F064

I have this Hmtl code..

```
<div class="product--price price--unit">
<span class="price--label label--purchase-unit">articlenumber:</span>
F064
</div>
```

I want to say if the F064 changes then alert what its changed to.
I want something like this in either JS or JQuery

```
var divTagVal = $("div.product--price");
    $(divTagVal).on('change', function () {
      alert(divTagVal);
    });
```

So if F064 changes to F065 the it should alert "F065"
but this doesnt work, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Even if this is possible, you're doing it the wrong way around. You should listen to the value, not to some text in HTML.

Comment: what do you mean by the wrong way around?

Comment: A `div` element does not emit the `"change"` event, the `"change"` event is for form elements.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Detect Content Change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15657686/383904)

Comment: try `alert($(this).text())` instead `alert(divTagVal)`