# innerHTML value of contenteditable div on modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a content editable div:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="my-div">
<? if(isset($data["description"])) {
       print_r($data["description"]);
} ?>
</div>
```

Once the user edits the div I am trying to pass the modified value of the div to a hidden form element.

```
document.getElementById("desc").value =document.getElementById("my-div").innerHTML();
```

I am getting the original value on page load, not the modified value as innerHTML.

How do I get the updated value?

Comment: change ".value" with ".innerHTML" and try again

Comment: Where's your code that captures the change in the contenteditable div? That one line isn't enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328102/how-to-detect-content-change-event-on-a-div You should attach a listener to the div. From what I see, you dont have a listener to the div. It does not detect the changes on dom element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#my-div').on('keypress', function() {
    $('#desc').val($(this).html());
});
```

you need to listen to changes to the editable div and update input value

i assume you use jquery if not

```
document.getElementById('my-div').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('desc').value = this.innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: "keypress" seems to not recognize the last typed character. I am using "keyup" instead.